# Responsive Filemanger, Laravel, Tinymce config

Tags: tinymce, laravel-5, responsive-filemanager

Where did I make mistake it does not show the TinyMCE and Reponsive Filemanager, This is their website:

[TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com)

[Responsive Filemanager](http://responsivefilemanager.com)

This is my folder structure:

```
--Home/example/
  --public_html
    --media
    --thumbs
  --laravel
    --vendor
      --filemanager
        --filemanager
          --dialog.php
          --config
            --config.php
    --resource
      --views
        --posts
          --edit.blade.php
  --mail
  --www
  --etc
```

TinyMCE config which is in edit.blade.php:

```
tinymce.init({
    .
    .
    .
   image_advtab: true ,
   relative_urls:false,
   auto_focus: "main_editor",
   entity_encoding: 'raw',
   paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
   },
   external_filemanager_path:"../laravel/vendor/filemanager/filemanager/",
   filemanager_title:"Filemanager",
   external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "../laravel/vendor/filemanager/filemanager/plugin.min.js"}
  });
```

Config of Responsive Filemanager which is in config.php:

```
'base_url' => 'http://example.com'
'upload_dir' => '/public_html/media/',
'current_path' => '../../../../public_html/media/',
'thumbs_base_path' => '../../../../public_html/thumbs/',
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible because Javascript is a client side script and cannot access outside the Public_html directory.

Answer (score 0):

external_filemanager_path and external_plugins path must be absolute so start with /
and don't touch base_url in config.php

Comment: Thanks a million Alberto, you are the best and your filemanager is awesome, wish you bests :)